# ventana modal no hace scroll

Tags: html, bootstrap

Estoy usando bootstrap para hacer ventanas modales pero cuando cargado mucho contenido no se puede bajar con el scroll para ver la demás información debido a que el scroll se oculta autmaticamente al abrir mi modal , es decir se queda estática, uso el código para las ventanas modales de la pagina de bootstrap

```html
        <div class="modal fade " id="modalOpcionessii" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
            <div class="modal-dialog"  role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Reporte de renovaciones</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="alert alert-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i> Propuestas</div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="valor_" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="valorboton_" />
                        <!-- EN EL DIV "muestraResultado" MUESTRO CONTENIDO DE TEXTO -->
                        <div id="muestraResultado"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SiRenueva" data-whatever="si">Si </button>
                        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#NoRenueva" data-whatever="si">No </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hola Drago25, podrias agregar tu codigo actual, asi te podemos ayudar mas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes resolverlo agregando esto a tu `css`

```
.modal-dialog{
    overflow-y: initial !important
}
.modal-body{
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/T0yF2ZNTUd

**Nota:** Recuerda que tu css tiene que aplicarse después de bootstrap.css

Comment: si quiero implementarlo únicamente a un solo modal, en lugar de tener esto ".modal-dialog" le daria otro nombre y aplicaría esa clase o id a mi modal verdad

Comment: así es, como está ahora aplica a todas las modales.